# align image on left text in line on right

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have code and it outputs the image and text that I require. The problem is I have tried all the css styles I can to try and get it to output the image on the left and text in line on the right. Can anybody help me please it seems the when it is outputted the alertblock and $service->serviceName  seemed to be outputting together rather than individual.

**template.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" />

    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="banner">             
            </div>

    <div id="alertblock"></div>


            <footer>
                <p>All rights reserved</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title></title>
            <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">,</script>

            <script src="js/sendrequest.js"></script>
            <script>$(document).ready(function(){
                sendRequest();
                setInterval(function(){
                  sendRequest();  
                },60000);
            })</script>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
<?php
include 'Template.php';
?>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

//$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');
$emails = imap_sort($inbox, SORTARRIVAL,1);

$output = '';

$jsonfile = file_get_contents("test.json");
$decoded = json_decode($jsonfile);

//print_r($jsonfile);


foreach ($decoded as $service) {

//print_r($service);

 echo "<div id=".$service->id."Service>";
        echo  $service->serviceName;


    foreach ($emails as $mail) {
        $looptimes =0;
        $headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $mail);

        //$output .= $headerInfo->subject . '<br/>';
        //print_r($headerInfo->subject);


    if ($headerInfo->subject == $service->downSubject) {
        // prints out image
        echo '<img src="Images/red.png";/>','<br>','<br>'; 

        break;

    }elseif ($headerInfo->subject == $service->upSubject) {
        echo'<img src="Images/green.png"; />','<br>','<br>';
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        $looptimes++;
    }
}
```

**sendrequest.js**

```
function sendRequest()
{
$("#alertblock").load("php/test.php", function () {
$(this).unwrap();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty hard to understand what your code is doing by how you set it up and it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you post the HTML you get inside the browser without the PHP so people can see the problem?

What is echo'ed first comes on the left side. Are you echo'ing the image first and then the text?

Example:

```html
<div id="idService">
  text first, before image
  <img src="http://flatable.phoenixcoded.net/default/assets/images/user.png"; /><br><br>
  
  
  
  

  <img src="http://flatable.phoenixcoded.net/default/assets/images/user.png"; />text after image<br><br>
</div>
```